# Calculating time spent on an app in mysql given name of the app and timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which stores the active window title and the app name and timestamp.

I'm trying to write sql query to know how much time is spent by the user grouped by appname or window title

i'm confused as to how to achieve as i need to group and add the time difference only until i hit a new appname or window title.

Please help in writing an sql query to achieve my objective

The structure of the table. is

```
1589972898969 | com.apple.Terminal | electron-quick-start
1589972893157 | com.google.Chrome  | Stafoverflow.com
```

The HTML

```
<table>
<tr><th>timestamp</th><th>appname</th><th>title</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>1589978510857</td>
<td>
FROM_UNIXTIME() Examples – MySQL | Database.Guide</td><td>com.apple.Terminal</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1589978507916</td>
<td>
FROM_UNIXTIME() Examples – MySQL | Database.Guide</td><td>com.apple.Terminal</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1589978501832</td>
<td>
FROM_UNIXTIME() Examples – MySQL | Database.Guide</td><td>com.apple.Terminal</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1589979493016</td>
<td>
Calculating time spent on an app in mysql given name of the app and timestamp - Stack Overflow </td><td>com.google.Chrome</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What does the timestamp represent? What do you mean by "add the time difference"? What's the query that you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: it is a unix timestamp. I tries grouping by appname and calculating cumulative sum, but unable to write a query when the appname changes after a period. i need to group by continuous time period and appname.  Something similar to what recuetime/timedoctor  app shows

Comment: will surely follow SO guidelines from the next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```sql
SELECT *, MAX(time), MIN(time), MAX(time) - MIN(time) time_diff FROM (

    SELECT  @c := @c + (@appname != appname) AS cn,
                @appname := appname AS an,
                t.*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @c := 0,
                        @appname := 0
                ) vars,
                test t
        ORDER BY `time` ASC
    ) sorted GROUP BY cn
```

Table to test:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `appname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `time`, `appname`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1,'2020-05-20 13:14:38','test','jhkjgh'),
    (2,'2020-05-20 13:15:11','test','skdljbhj'),
    (3,'2020-05-20 13:18:11','test',NULL),
    (4,'2020-05-20 14:24:38','test2','jhkjgh'),
    (5,'2020-05-20 14:55:31','test1','skdljbhj'),
    (6,'2020-05-20 15:38:11','test1',NULL),
    (7,'2020-05-20 18:24:38','test2','jhkjgh'),
    (8,'2020-06-20 09:55:31','test2','skdljbhj'),
    (9,'2020-05-10 05:38:11','test2',NULL);
```

I did it with timestamps, you can change that. Also you can add whatever grouping you like.

Comment: thanks a ton, this solved the purpose. i will digin to understand the syntax. new to sql.